# How would I instrument Sequelize with opentracing?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, opentracing

I'd like to start tracing my sequelize SQL calls using opentracing, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how.

I'd like to adapt this code to be more flexible so I can drop it into any sequelize project: https://github.com/instana/nodejs-sensor/blob/626ab3c8258d4e91d42a61d79603532a921b35b4/packages/core/src/tracing/instrumentation/database/pg.js

I'm using Lightstep as a tracer, but I am using a raw tracer (not one that auto instruments) because I like the control.

Do you have suggestions on how I could add tracing to sequelize/postgres(pg)?

Comment: did you find a good way to do this? I'm on a similar situation, but with mysql.

Comment: I am interested in that too